# Conditionally render partials in application layout

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial

In a Rails 3 application layout i include a partial for flash messages.
While this is ok in most cases, there is a view where I would need flash messages appear in another place;
is there a way in layouts/application.html.erb to say something like

```
<%= render 'layout/messages' unless somecondition %>
```

where somecondition is something able to detect that I am in 'myview/index'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure is, <strike>use `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]`</strike> actually you should use `controller_name` and `action_name` [per the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters)

```
<%= render 'layout/messages' 
  if controller_name == 'myview' && action_name == 'index' %>
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for. This perfectly solves the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a bit cleaner: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/no-content-for-you